# Android U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR when populating a custom view in a ListFragment

Tags: android

I tried to combine those two source codes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697716/listview-displays-each-item-twice-after-filtering and http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/) in order to make two tabs in which one of them has a listview with a searchbox.

```
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment implements OnTabChangeListener {

private static final String TAG = "FragmentTabs";
public static final String TAB_ALLSERVICES = "allservices";
public static final String TAB_MOSTUSEDSERVICES = "mostusedservices";

private View mRoot;
private TabHost mTabHost;
private int mCurrentTab;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mRoot = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabs_fragment, null);
    mTabHost = (TabHost) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    setupTabs();
    return mRoot;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(mCurrentTab);
    // manually start loading stuff in the first tab
    updateTab(TAB_ALLSERVICES, R.id.tab_1);
}

private void setupTabs() {
    mTabHost.setup(); // important!
    mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_ALLSERVICES, R.string.tab_allservices,
            R.id.tab_1));
    mTabHost.addTab(newTab(TAB_MOSTUSEDSERVICES,
            R.string.tab_mostusedservices, R.id.tab_2));
}

private TabSpec newTab(String tag, int labelId, int tabContentId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "buildTab(): tag=" + tag);

    View indicator = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(
            R.layout.tab,
            (ViewGroup) mRoot.findViewById(android.R.id.tabs), false);
    ((TextView) indicator.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(labelId);

    TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
    tabSpec.setIndicator(indicator);
    tabSpec.setContent(tabContentId);
    return tabSpec;
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTabChanged(): tabId=" + tabId);
    if (TAB_ALLSERVICES.equals(tabId)) {
        updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_1);
        mCurrentTab = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (TAB_MOSTUSEDSERVICES.equals(tabId)) {
        updateTab(tabId, R.id.tab_2);
        mCurrentTab = 1;
        return;
    }

}

private void updateTab(String tabId, int placeholder) {
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.findFragmentByTag(tabId) == null) {
        if (tabId.equals(TAB_MOSTUSEDSERVICES)) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(placeholder, new MostUsedServicesFragment(), tabId)
                    .commit();
        } else if (tabId.equals(TAB_ALLSERVICES)) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(placeholder, new Fragmenttest(), tabId)
            .commit();
        }
    }
}
}

tabs_fragment.xml looks like following:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#EFEFEF">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

public class Fragmenttest extends ListFragment {
ListView newReqList;
LayoutInflater inflater;
String[] from = new String[] { "mainrow", "subrow" };
EditText searchBar = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> sAdapter = null;
private static final String[] NUMBERS = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "VI",
        "VII", "VIII", "IX", "X", "XI", "XII", "XIII", "XIV", "XV" };

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    newReqList = this.getListView();

    searchBar = (EditText) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_box);
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s : NUMBERS) {
        l.add(s);
    }
    sAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(),
            R.layout.list_item, l);
    newReqList.setAdapter(sAdapter);
    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(filterTextWatcher);
}

private TextWatcher filterTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {
        sAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        sAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

};

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.allservices, container, false);
    return v;
}
}
```

The allservices.xml looks like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Pretty hint text, and maxLines -->

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search_box"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/allserviceshint"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<!-- Set height to 0, and let the weight param expand it -->
<!--
     Note the use of the default ID! This lets us use a 
     ListActivity still!
-->

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As soon as I run the application, I get following LogCat:

```
04-19 04:59:04.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4106): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-19 04:59:04.276: E/AndroidRuntime(4106): java.lang.RuntimeException: U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR
```

Does anyone know what that means and how I can fix it?

Best Regards, Roman.

Comment: Please add a complete stack trace

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but I've solved the problem already. If you are still interested in the complete stack trace, I can start the Application again with the old xml file and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the Problem by changing the allservices.xml to following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Hallo"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLines="1" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No items."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Adding a Framelayout did the trick. I think without the FrameLayout the Listview made the Edittext disappear and so the U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR was thrown.